# Does on-the-fly list creation and return in a function create a memory leak in Python?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

If I create a list in a python function and return it to the caller, how does garbage collection work on that list?  Do I have to do anything to keep a memory leak from occurring?

For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

class Example:
    def f1(self):
        list = []
        len = random.randint(0, 30)
        for i in range (0, len):
                list.append(random.randint(0, 65536))
        return list


random.seed(None)

e = Example()
while (1):
    l = e.f1()
```

Will this cause a memory leak?  Does the 'list' in f1() have an appropriate reference count at all times?  Does the caller of f1() have to do anything to keep a memory leak from occurring?  Should the caller do a del() on the list or something?

Comment: `list` is a reserved Python keyword, it is recommended that one abstains from using it as a name of a list.

Comment: yeah, that's right...use alist, rlist instead

Comment: You should also avoid calling a variable `len` as that will mask access to the `len` builtin function.

Comment: and other two advice; i never used random.seed, it's not necessary, i think...however, what you don't need are the parenthesis in while (1)...simply write while 1, or better, while True...and finally you should write class Example(object):#ecc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no memory leak here. The list assigned to `l` is the *same* list that is generated in the function. Python passes objects, not references or values.

Python keeps track of the references to that list: on each iteration of the `while` loop, a new list is created and assigned to `l`. This causes the previous one to no longer have any references, so it will be deleted.

Comment: **Python passes references** (to objects) - "references" in the e.g. Java sense, not references in the C++ sense. That's why `def f(x): x = Stuff()` does nothing while `def g(x): x.ham = Ham()` mutates the argument.

Answer (score 2):

in python it's all automatic...most of time you don't have to worry about garbage collections...

in this case, the func create a list and returns it. then you assign it to l.

once you assign a value to a non-empty var, the first value it's simply throw out, there is no memory leaks, you dont' have to use del..

it's, cool, isn't it? :)